# Is safe to remove the files name off.xxx in /var/lib/mysql/?

Tags: mysql

Today, my HDD is full usage with the folder `/var/lib/mysql/`.

There are the hundreds of files with name off.000001, off.000002,... off.000190 and one file with name off.index.

What do they mean and can I remove all of them?

Comment: For the love of your data.  Please perform a FULL Backup before you do anything.  Also, when you are unsure, **move** not remove.  Once you have verified you haven't broken anything, then you can remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is either your binary log or your relay log.... if you do not have a master/slave setup, comment out all "bin-log" and "relay-log" entries in /etc/my.cnf, restart mysql, and delete all those files.

if you do have a master/slave setup, i believe you there is an "expire-log" directive now, or you can just cron "find /var/lib/mysql -name "off.*" -mtime +3 -delete" or something like that.

Comment: thank for you reply. I found no bin-log, relay-log or expire-log in /etc/my.cnf . Can I turn these log files off in the future?

Comment: do a "show master status" and a "show slave status"